# CSS: custom bullets: joined as timeline

Tags: css, sass, html-lists

I am building a vertical timeline as a < ul > with the < li >s as events. **This is the intent:**

[image: joined bullets]

I've customized the bullets easily enough, and I made the vertical line with a background-gradient; the one thing I haven't been able to do is terminate the vertical line at top and bottom.

**So far, it looks like this:**

[image]

My SCSS code:

```
ul.timeline {
    list-style: none;
    color: red;
    font-size: .8em;
    /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#ffffff+0,ffffff+5,d8d8d8+6,d8d8d8+7,ffffff+8,ffffff+100 */
    background: #ffffff; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #ffffff 0%, #ffffff 1px, #d8d8d8 2px, #d8d8d8 3px, #ffffff 4px, #ffffff 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #ffffff 0%,#ffffff 1px, #d8d8d8 2px, #d8d8d8 3px, #ffffff 4px,#ffffff 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #ffffff 0%,#ffffff 1px, #d8d8d8 2px, #d8d8d8 3px, #ffffff 4px,#ffffff 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */

    background-position: 29px 0;

    li {

        &::before {
            content: "\26AB";
            font-size: 1.3em;
            color: #d8d8d8;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 1em;
            margin-left: -1em;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }

        a {
            color: black;
            text-decoration: underline;
        }
    }
}
```

My HTML code:

```
<ul class="timeline">
  <li><a href="">asd as</a></li>
  <li><a href="">werwer we</a></li>
</ul>
```

I know I can scrap the whole custom-bullet and background-gradient css and do this with background-images, I was just hoping to find a css-only solution.

Comment: Have you looked at `:first-child` and `:last-child`?

Comment: First of all, you're showing us SCSS code, not CSS code. Second, you'll need to show us more of your code. You can use [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/yufqzpur/) as a starting point if you want!

Comment: JZ: I know about F/C and L/C, but because i'm using a gradient I can't affect their height.
JS: Not sure why SCSS is a problem. Just code formatting in this case. I could rearrange if that would help. also not sure what other code you'd want to see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use pseudo-elements for this, one for circle and other one for the line, and `:not(:last-child)` so you don't set line on last element.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
}
li a {
  color: gray;
}
li:before {
  content: '';
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #D8D8D8;
  position: absolute;
  left: -15px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-40%);
}

li:not(:last-child):after {
  content: '';
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #D8D8D8;
  position: absolute;
  left: -8px;
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="timeline">
  <li><a href="">asd as</a></li>
  <li><a href="">werwer we</a></li>
  <li><a href="">werwer we</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

Method using background-gradient...

```css
ul.timeline {
  list-style: none;
  color: red;
  font-size: .8em;
  position: relative;
}

.timeline::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 80px;
  width: 30px;
  top: 6px;
  left: 0;
  background: radial-gradient(circle, grey 20%, transparent 20%);
  background-size: 50px 25px;
}

.timeline::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  top: 8px;
  left: 24px;
  height: 70px;
  width: 1px;
  background: grey;
}

.timeline li {
  padding: .5em;
}

a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<ul class="timeline">
  <li><a href="">asd as</a></li>
  <li><a href="">werwer we</a></li>
  <li><a href="">werwer we</a></li>
</ul>
```